# Where does Pica's body go when he uses his fruit?

Tags: one-piece

Pica uses the Stone Stone fruit, which in recent episodes, shows him

> turning into a giant stone colossus.

But, what happens to his human body when he uses his fruit in this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, in the most recent episode you saw

> Ruffy destroying the head of the big stone giant Pica created, while Zorro states, that the stone body is just a hull and that Pica can recreate it. Only seconds later you see Pica coming out of the stone body itself, so I guess it is not wrong to say: He hides somwhere insided the stone body he created.

Comment: It's funny and maybe sad, that Pica was not defeated only until most recent chapters... But you are right. Pica's body can move freely anywhere in the stone he is manipulating. Which makes him pretty hard to pinpoint in a place like Dressrosa.